# python multiprocessing with maxtasksperchild

Tags: python, multiprocessing

EDIT: I confirmed this to be bug in Python. It is bug http://bugs.python.org/issue10332 (I filed a new bug, in response to which the maintainer pointed me to 10332). I copied the multiprocessing directory from Python source repo into my project directory, and the testcase works properly now.

This seemingly-simple program isn't working for me unless I remove the maxtasksperchild parameter. What am I doing wrong?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import sys

def f(x):
  print "pid: ", os.getpid(), " got: ", x
  sys.stdout.flush()
  return [x, x+1]

def cb(r):
  print "got result: ", r

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = Pool(processes=1, maxtasksperchild=9)
  keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  result = pool.map_async(f, keys, chunksize=1, callback=cb)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

When I run it, I get:

```
$ python doit.py
pid:  6409  got:  1
pid:  6409  got:  2
pid:  6409  got:  3
pid:  6409  got:  4
pid:  6409  got:  5
pid:  6409  got:  6
pid:  6409  got:  7
pid:  6409  got:  8
pid:  6409  got:  9
```

And it hangs. That is, the new worker to process the 10th element didn't get spawned.

In another terminal, I see:

```
$ ps -C python
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6408 pts/11   00:00:00 python
 6409 pts/11   00:00:00 python <defunct>
```

This is done on Ubuntu 11.10 running python 2.7.2+ (installed from ubuntu packages).

Comment: I think this is a bug in python. My call to pool.close() (which the docs say I should call before calling pool.join()), sets the flag pool._state to CLOSE. The function Pool._handle_workers relies on that flag being 'RUN' to kick of new worker processes.

One workaround for the bug is to sleep after the map_async call for about 10 seconds until pool.close() is called. I will probably file a bug against python.

Comment: I can confirm this hevaiour. Having python 2.7.2 , faced same  issue with maxtasksperchild=1. Script hanged at the finall pool.join() after all tasks were successfuly done, leaving all child processes zombie (<defunct>). Removing this parameter from pool creation - resolved the issue.

Comment: was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0):

maxtasksperchild mean one processing execute maximum number of tasks。

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in python3.

```
pid:  18316  got:  1
pid:  18316  got:  2
pid:  18316  got:  3
pid:  18316  got:  4
pid:  18316  got:  5
pid:  18316  got:  6
pid:  18316  got:  7
pid:  18316  got:  8
pid:  18316  got:  9
pid:  18317  got:  10
got result:  [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10], [10, 11]]
```