# Script hangs during execution leaving <defunct> child processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to speedup archiving of files by using multiprocessing.

```
pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,maxtasksperchild=1)
for file_name in files :
    p_output=pool.map(gzip_file,[file_name])
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

function `gzip_file` does simple gzip , logging whether it was success or not.

My issue is , that during SOME runs of this script it hangs indefinitelly and  is see no load on the machine.
Is it wrong to call `pool.map` for each file?

**UPDATE:**  I've switched to  `map_async` but this did not helped.
When script hangs, now it happens all the time, child processes became zombie. 
That  is really strange.

**RESOLUTION:** This issue is a bug in python 2.7.2  ,  related to   `maxtasksperchild` parameter of the pool. As soon as I removed this parameter  and left it to default, all became working as expected.
More details in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859222/python-multiprocessing-with-maxtasksperchild?rq=1)

Comment: `pool.map` "[blocks until the result is ready](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map)".  You are only feeding the pool one file at a time.  That seems odd to me.  Why aren't you doing `p_output = pool.map(gzip_file, files)`?  (Note that this does not explain why your script hangs.)  Disclaimer - I have never used `multiprocessing`.  I have only skimmed the docs.

Comment: i would expect one instance of pool.map , pick up one task and use  1  core to do archiving. And this should happend 4 times in paralell , one pool.map with archiving task per core.  As soon as one of cores became free, next pool.map should come to play.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  `pool.map` "blocks until the result is ready".  You need to pass the whole iterable to `map`.  Otherwise you it will block on each single item iterable it is passed.

Comment: Although you have found a fix for your script hanging, you will not be working tasks in parallel unless you give `pool.map` the entire iterable.