# Python Apply_async not waiting for other Processes to Finish

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have the following sample code that I am trying to use the multiprocessing module on.  The following statement had been working previously under other applications, but one process (which receives a very small amount of data just due to the breakup) finishes first and causes the program to finish.  Could someone help me understand why this is not waiting for the others?

```
def mpProcessor(basePath, jsonData, num_procs = mp.cpu_count()):
manager = mp.Manager()
map = manager.dict()
procs = mp.Pool(processes = num_procs, maxtasksperchild = 1)
chunkSize = len(jsonData) / (num_procs)
dataChunk = [(i, i + chunkSize) for i in range(0, len(jsonData), chunkSize)]
count = 1
for i in dataChunk:
    print 'test'
    s, e = i
    procs.apply_async(processJSON, args = (count, basePath, jsonData[s:e]))
    count += 1
procs.close()
procs.join()
return map

def processJSON(proc, basePath, records):
print 'Spawning new process: %d' %os.getpid()
outDict = dict()
print len(records)
for i in range(len(records)):
    valid = False
    idx = 0
    while valid == False:
        jsonObject = json.loads(records[i][1])['results'][idx]
        if jsonObject['kind'] == 'song':
            valid = True
            break
        else:
            idx += 1
    tunesTrack = Track()
    tunesTrack.setTrackId(jsonObject['trackId'])
print 'Finished processing %d records with process %d' %(len(records), os.getpid())
```

Comment: Try a `get` on the `result` object returned by `apply_async`.

Comment: Setting `maxtasksperchild = 1` and also setting a chunksize greater than 1 are at cross purposes. I'm not sure what the iteraction is supposed to be, but there may even be a bug in python when you do it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859222/python-multiprocessing-with-maxtasksperchild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be reinventing the wheel.

What you are trying to do could be much more easily achieved by using an initializer with the pool and using `map` rather than `apply_async`. As it stands your code snippet is not runnable so I can't be sure what the actual problem is. However, the following should simplify your code and make it easier to debug.

```
import math
import multiprocessing as mp

def pool_init(basePath_):
    global basePath, job_count
    basePath = basePath_
    job_count = 0
    print 'Spawning new process: %d' %os.getpid()

def mpProcessor(basePath, jsonData, num_procs=mp.cpu_count()):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_procs, initializer=pool_init, initargs=(basePath,))
    # could specify a chunksize, but multiprocessing works out the optimal chunksize
    return pool.map(processJSON, jsonData)

# change processJSON to work with single records and
# remove proc and basePath args (as not needed)
def processJSON(record):
    global job_count
    print 'Starting job %d in process: %d' % (job_count, os.getpid())
    valid = False
    idx = 0
    while valid == False:
        jsonObject = json.loads(record[1])['results'][idx]
        if jsonObject['kind'] == 'song':
            valid = True
            break
        else:
            idx += 1
    tunesTrack = Track()
    tunesTrack.setTrackId(jsonObject['trackId'])
    print 'Finished processing job %d with process %d' % (job_count,  os.getpid())
    job_count += 1
```